# Using class instances in react state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class

```js
class Booper{
  constructor(){
    this.boops = 0;
  }
}
```

and a react component using this class to maintain some state

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const App = () => {
  const [booper, setBooper] = useState(new Booper());

  const handleClick = () => {
    booper.boops = booper.boops+1;
    setBooper(booper);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {booper.boops}<br/>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        Boop? :(
      </button><br/>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

However react doesn't seem to trigger a re-draw when i click the button.

If i add the following it does work.

```js
const App = () => {
  ...

  const clone = (original) => {
    return Object.assign(Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(original)), original)
  }

  const handleClickWithClone = () => {
    const cloned = clone(booper)
    cloned.boops = cloned.boops+1
    setBooper(cloned);
  }

  ...

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      <button onClick={handleClickWithClone}>
        Boop! :)
      </button><br/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

However, i'm not entirely sure that this is the way to go. I don't know if the garbage collector will clean up all the cloned object. Or if there are other performance issues with this solution.

Is there a better way of using class instances in react states?

(full fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ho6fka1x/2/)

Comment: If all the class does is hold a number, it would be much easier to simply set a number into state instead. Classes are generally useful when you want to tie together *data* with *methods* that operate on that data

Comment: This is a simplified version of a similar situation i have. In the real example there is a bunch of functionality on the class as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mutating the state directly which will not cause re-render.

**This should work**

```js
const handleClick = () => {
    // booper.boops = booper.boops + 1; //<---remove this
    setBooper(prev => ({...prev, boops: prev.boops + 1}));
  };
```